# Memory error while trying to search every data frame column entry for value corresponding to 'Id'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

I have a data frame columns which consists of values in the format as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c':[{'name': 'Paramount Pictures', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'United Artists', 'id': 60}, {'name': 'Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM)', 'id': 8411}]})

df
                  c
0            {'name': 'Paramount Pictures', 'id': 4}
1               {'name': 'United Artists', 'id': 60}
2  {'name': 'Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM)', 'id': 8411}
```

I want to extract all the values corresponding to Ids, e.g 4,60,8411. I have written the following code for it:

```
def FindIdInColumn(column,callBack,fieldName):
    for i in range(0,len(column)):
        collectionJson = column[i]
        if type(collectionJson) !=str or collectionJson == '':
            continue
        idIndex = 0
        idIndex = collectionJson.find(fieldName,idIndex,len(collectionJson))
        while idIndex != -1:
            idStr = ''
            j = idIndex+5
            while j<len(collectionJson) and collectionJson[j]!=',':
                if not(collectionJson[j].isspace()) and collectionJson[j].isnumeric():
                    idStr = idStr + collectionJson[j]
                j=j+1
            callBack(i,idStr)
            idIndex = idIndex+2
            idIndex = collectionJson.find(fieldName,idIndex,len(collectionJson))
```

Here column is the data frame column, fieldName is 'Id', and callback is the function that is to be called after extracting the Id value. 
This function is consuming a lot of RAM, as I am running this function on 7 columns. Is there a way to optimize this function to use les memory.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df['column'].tolist()).loc[:,'id']` ?

Comment: @anky_91 I am getting key error, after trying this code. There can be multiple ids in a single cell. Could this have caused the issue?

Comment: replace `column` with the original column name?

Comment: Yes, I replaced the column name

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have done:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c':[{'name': 'Paramount Pictures', 'id': 4}, 
                             {'name': 'United Artists', 'id': 60}, 
                             {'name': 'Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM)', 'id': 8411}]})

df['id'] = df.apply(lambda r: dict(r['c'])['id'], axis=1)

df['id'].tolist()
[4, 60, 8411]
```

Comment: I am getting "('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required', 'occurred at index 0')" while trying the above solution. What could be the problem?